# PUT and PATCH request from Console Application

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, patch, put

I was trying to make put,post and patch calls from console application, I was able to perform post successfully, but I'm not able to perform put and patch.

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddr);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PutAsJsonAsync(entityAddress, entity).Result;
```

Please suggest any approach.

Comment: What version of .Net are you using? Also, are you receiving an error or is the request not producing the results you expect?

Comment: .Net Framework 4.5 the error I'm getting is "Inavlid Operation"